# tcpdump option to find process initiate communication

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I am using the Linux command line and when I run the following command:

```
 tcpdump -n dst host destsitename
 tcpdump -n dst host stackoverflow.com
```

to see if my server as source talk to this domain, how I can find out which process doing the communication from my server as source.

My question is which option should I use in "tcpdump".

Comment: tcpdump cannot do that for you. Use `netstat` and similar tools to find which processes own which sockets.

Answer (score 2):

On linux you can also use the `ss` command (which replaces the deprecated `netstat` command):

```
$ ss -p dst stackoverflow.com
Netid                State                Recv-Q                Send-Q                                 Local Address:Port                                   Peer Address:Port                 Process
tcp                  ESTAB                0                     0                                        192.168.2.5:50676                                 151.101.65.69:https                 users:(("firefox",pid=4657,fd=251))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `netstat -avnp` and fetch the `<pid>` (the last column)
2. Run `ps -ef | fgrep <pid>` and see what that `<pid>` belongs to

Comment: when i do tcpdupm i got  14:46:36.702758 IP 10.64.13.205.50356 > 64.15.129.80.80: Flags [S], seq 1677599293, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4013456 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
  But how to use netstat if i dont know the process name even ?  btw all traffic gose to 64.15.129.80.80:

Comment: netstat will give you all connections on the server and respective `pid`s, you can `|grep` the address/port of interest

Answer (score 1):

If you know the port, you can try:

```
lsof -i :1234
```

The benefits of using `lsof` instead of `netstat` is that the `-p` is not supported on Unix/OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Use lsof and grep by site name:

```
$: lsof -i |grep mapscii.me
$: telnet    16678 zersh    3u  IPv4 1789302  0t0  TCP 192.168.21.180:43148->mapscii.me:telnet (ESTABLISHED)
```

or netstat:

```
$ netstat anlpt |grep mapscii.me
tcp        0      0 192.168.21.180:43168    mapscii.me:telnet       ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use next script:

```
LOCAL_IP="src_ip"
TARGET_IP="..."

while read x; do

  port=$( echo $x | grep "IP ${LOCAL_IP}" | awk '{print $3}' | sed "s/${LOCAL_IP}.//" )

  if [ ! -z ${port} ]; then
    lsof -Pni :${port}
  fi

done <<< "$( tcpdump -nn -c1 host ${TARGET_IP} )"
```

PS. In my case it only worked in the background. Hung in processes for more than 10 hours looking for the source of the problem:

```
while read x; do port=$(echo $x | grep "IP ${LOCAL_IP}" | awk '{print $3}' | sed "s/${LOCAL_IP}.//"); if [ ! -z ${port} ]; then lsof -Pni :${port}; fi; done <<< "$( tcpdump -nn -c2 host ${TARGET_IP} )" >> /tmp/result &
```